# How to export User Rights Assignments and import them on another machine

Tags: windows-server-2008, command-line-interface, scripting, security, user-permissions

How would one export all of the user rights assignments from one Windows Server 2008 box and import them on another. Neither would be on a domain so this would just be local security policy.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just had to right click on enough stuff :-)

You can export by right-clicking on Security Settings in `secpol.msc` and selecting export. This creates an INF of the User Rights Assignments which can be imported using the same method on another computer only selecting Import instead.

Comment: @Tom It won't let before two days ;-).

Comment: @AndyArismendi Thanks, it helped me. However, is there any way to do it in CMD? (or should we remove `command-line` tag from question?)